# Have doubts that it's right equivalency of predicates when there are two people with different tastes.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

$L(x)$ means "person $x$ from our town loves lolicon."

$G(x)$ means "person $x$ from our town loves guro."

Both of $L(x)$ and $G(x)$ share the same universe.

The equivalency in question is
$$\exists x L(x) \lor \exists x G(x) \equiv \exists x ( L(x) \lor G(x) )$$

I translate the left part as "Somebody in our town loves lolicon and/or somebody in our town loves guro."

I translate the right part as "Somebody in our town loves lolicon and/or loves guro."

Let's assume that there are only two such freaks in our little town, one loves lolicon and the other one loves guro.

The left side of the equivalency would be true under such assumption. But I worry for the right side.

My reasoning is following:

It seems for me that we can interpret $\exists x ( L(x) \lor G(x) )$ as prediction of tastes for the whole group of freaks that has size $\ge 1$.
"There is a group consisting of one or more person(s) in our town whose members all either love lolicon or love guro or love both guro and lolicon". So if this group consists of two persons, then either both of them love guro or both of them love lolicon or both of them love guro and lolicon at the same time. There *can't* be a situation when one loves guro and the other one loves lolicon.

I would like to see my if reasoning is true or false. And why.

Comment: The two are logically equivalent, that means that they **must** have the same truth value in every "universe" : with one guy, two or more... The RHS asserts that "There is (at least) one guy that : either loves Lolicon or loves Guro". This does not preclude that there are more than one, and does not says that he (the guy) has to love both: "either loves L or loves G".

Comment: What does "RHS" mean?

Comment: I didn't say that here must be only one guy who loves both lolicon and guro!

Comment: "There can't be a situation when one loves guro and the other one loves lolicon." In a universe with two person : John and Mary, where John loves Lolicon the formula is *true*, irespective of the fact that Mary loves or not someone. What I'm trying to say is that you cannot "prove" the formula reasoning with specific example, like a universe of two guys... :-)

Comment: This example with two people is just the simplest form for more general case, when n people like G and k people like L. You can easily go from one to another. And let's return back to the business, so far I don't see what's wrong with my interpretation of the right predicate.

Comment: Last comment... "There can't be a situation when one loves guro and the other one loves lolicon" is wrong. A universe where John loves Lolicon and Mary loves Guro is **not** a counterexample to the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently learnt about method of finite universe. Application of this method to universe consisting out of two people 
discovers that there is no need to worry about the right hand statement.

Let the universe consists of a and b. Then we can reformulate our statement in following way:

[(La v Lb) v (Ga v Gb)] <=> [ (La v Ga) v (Lb v Gb)   ]

Firstly, please notice that the right part of our logical equality is just rearranged left part. According to properties of
associativity and commutativity of "OR" said parts must be logically equal.

Secondly, just to make it obvious HOW situation "One loves guro, another loves lolicon" does NOT turn the right part into a
false statement, here goes proof:

Initially:

(La v Ga) v (Lb v Gb)

Then:

(F v T) v (T v F)

Then:

T v T

And finally:

T